# Form Fields outside dropzone box

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

I am using `dropzone.js` for drag and drop file upload. I also have two fields and a submit button, but they only appear in the preview pane despite it being in it's own `<div>` tag. I would like it to appear below the

CSS:

```
    #attachmentdropzone {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 3px dashed #0000FF;
        padding: 30px 0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<form action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="attachmentdropzone">

    <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    <div class="container">

        <input type="email" name="username"/>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>

        <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Current layout that I'd like to fix. I would like the form fields and button outside the blue dotted line.

[image]

EDIT: in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/boavzunL/

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI updated. I would like the fields and button outside the blue dashed line while still be part of the form

Comment: Can you show your code on JSFiddle?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI https://jsfiddle.net/boavzunL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a following CSS Class([Your Example](https://jsfiddle.net/boavzunL/2/)):

```
.container {
     position: absolute;
    margin-top: 75px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you try dragging an dropping in a file. Something got messed up as it displays dozens of lines of html code after dropping in a file.

Comment: @user2242044 because you didn't provide a valid action i.e.(action="{{ url_for('upload') }}").